# How to login with Rest API using flutter dart

Tags: rest, http-post

I have created a login form with email, password a login button.
I am new to flutter dart and web.

I don't know how create login app using Rest API in flutter. I already have Login Rest API and its working fine on Postman using post request.

how to create login system in flutter using http post request?

Answer (score 7):

This example might be helpful:[Flutter: Login App using REST API and SQFLite](https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-login-app-using-rest-api-and-sqflite-b4815aed2149)

Basically, what it does is:

- Use dart's http package to send post/get requests, encapsulated in NetworkUtil class.
- RestDataSource do the login() and return a User instance.
- LoginScreenPresenter defines an interface for LoginScreen view and a presenter that incorporates all business logic specific to login screen itself.
- The view LoginScreen contains the login form.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method which provide authentication.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String pass='123456789'
String email='mrmodh10@gmail.com'

authenticate(String email, String pass) async {
    String myurl =
        "here pass your url";
    http.post(myurl, headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'authorization': 'pass your key(optional)'
    }, body: {
      "email": email,
      "password": pass
    }).then((response) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);     

  }
```